# Get all the objects from a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

So, I have something like this:

```
objArray1 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 4}, { candidate2: "Paul", votes: 3}];

objArray2 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 7}, { candidate2: "Ben", votes: 3}, { candidate3: "Melisa", votes:8 }];
```

I am trying to use javascript to make an array with all the candidates and see how many votes each of them have. The part to calculate the votes is easy, but I don't know how to put all the candidates in one array.

I should get an array with: Alex, Paul, Ben and Melisa.

Thank you!

Comment: You should not give each element "candidate" a number at the end. Instead, just call it candidate and if you need an id, have an id field. Then you can easily do objArray1.concat(objArray2).map(function(entry){return entry.candidate});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var candidates = [];
var found = 0;
for(var i=0;objArray1.length>i;i++){
    found = 0;
    //add votes to candidate array
    for(var j=0;candidates.length>j;j++){
        if(candidates[j].name==objArray1[i][Object.keys(objArray1[i])[0]]){
           candidates[j].votes = candidates[j].votes+objArray1[i].votes;
           found = 1;
        }
    }
    //if condidate not found in votes array, create new
    if(found==0){
         var tmp = {};
         tmp.name = objArray1[i].candidate;
         tmp.votes = objArray1[i].votes;
         //add to array
         candidates.push(tmp);
    }
}

console.log(candidates);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hashtable and group by name.

```js
var array1 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 4}, { candidate2: "Paul", votes: 3}],
    array2 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 7}, { candidate2: "Ben", votes: 3}, { candidate3: "Melisa", votes:8 }],
    grouped = [array1, array2].reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            a.forEach(function (o, i) {
                var name = o['candidate' + (i + 1)];
                if (!hash[name]) {
                    hash[name] = { candidate: name, votes: 0 };
                    r.push(hash[name]);
                }
                hash[name].votes += o.votes;
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate an object which holds property name as name and vote count as value.

```js
var objArray1 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 4}, { candidate2: "Paul", votes: 3}], objArray2 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 7}, { candidate2: "Ben", votes: 3}, { candidate3: "Melisa", votes:8 }];

var res = []
  // cobine two arrays
  .concat(objArray1, objArray2)
  // iterate over the arrays
  .reduce(function(obj, o) {
    // get the key except the votes
    var key = Object.keys(o).find(function(k) {
      return k != 'votes';
    })
    // define property if not already defined
    obj[key] = obj[key] || 0;
    // add the vote count
    obj[key] += o.votes;
    // return object refernece
    return obj;
    // set initial value as empty object
  }, {});

console.log(res);
// get the names array if need
console.log(Object.keys(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of names as you asked

```
var rawArrays = objArray1.concat(objArray2), Candidates = [], tmp = []
for (var i in rawArrays) {
    tmp[rawArrays[i][Object.keys(rawArrays[i])[0]]] = 1
}
Candidates = Object.keys(tmp)
```

To get array with candidates and votes sum

```
var rawArrays = objArray1.concat(objArray2), Candidates = []

for (var i in rawArrays) {
    name = rawArrays[i][Object.keys(rawArrays[i])[0]]
    if (Candidates[name]) Candidates[name] += rawArrays[i].votes
    else Candidates[name] = rawArrays[i].votes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `Array.prototype.concat()`, `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.map()` functions:

```js
var objArray1 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 4}, { candidate2: "Paul", votes: 3}],
    objArray2 = [ { candidate1: "Alex" , votes: 7}, { candidate2: "Ben", votes: 3}, { candidate3: "Melisa", votes:8 }],
    
    grouped = objArray1.concat(objArray2).reduce(function(r, o){
        var k = Object.keys(o).filter(function(k){
                return k.indexOf('candidate') === 0; 
            })[0];

        (r[o[k]])? r[o[k]].votes += o.votes : r[o[k]] = {candidate: o[k], votes: o.votes};
        return r;
    }, {}),

    result = Object.keys(grouped).map(function(k){ return grouped[k]; });
    
console.log(result);
```